# thermal printer java

Tags: java, printing

Please help trying to print in a thermal printer using this code, I get a print job in my system tray but my thermal printer doesnt print.
PrintReceiptUtil class:

```
import java.awt.JobAttributes;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;

import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;

import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;


public static void doPrintReceipt() throws IOException, PrintException{

    String defaultPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
    System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter);
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    // prints the famous hello world! plus a form feed
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello world!\f".getBytes("UTF8"));

    PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    pras.add(new Copies(1));

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
    job.print(doc, pras);
    pjw.waitForDone();
    is.close();
} 
}
```

PrintJobWatcher Class: for monitoring print jobs I get to "printing done" but my thermal printer does not print anything

```
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;

public PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job){

    job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
        public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            allDone();
        }
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            allDone();
        }
        public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            allDone();
        }
        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            allDone();
        }
        void allDone() {
            synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
                done = true;
                System.out.println("Printing done ...");
                PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
            }
        }
    });
}

public synchronized void waitForDone() {
    try {
        while (!done) {
            wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some indentation to make it more readable for people.

Comment: Your PrintJobListener does the same thing for every end result case.  You should probably add different cases for each, so that if printJobFailed is being thrown, you would actually know it failed.

Answer (score 7):

working version of @bhuvanpavan

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.OrientationRequested;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class NewClass {

    public void a() {
        PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
        Paper paper = new Paper();

        double paperWidth = 3;//3.25
        double paperHeight = 3.69;//11.69
        double leftMargin = 0.12;
        double rightMargin = 0.10;
        double topMargin = 0;
        double bottomMargin = 0.01;

        paper.setSize(paperWidth * 200, paperHeight * 200);
        paper.setImageableArea(leftMargin * 200, topMargin * 200,
                (paperWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin) * 200,
                (paperHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin) * 200);

        format.setPaper(paper);

        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
//testing 

        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        Printable printable = new ReceiptPrint();

        format = printerJob.validatePage(format);
        boolean don = printerJob.printDialog();
        printerJob.setPrintable(printable, format);
        try {
            printerJob.print(aset);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class ReceiptPrint implements Printable {

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
    String receiptDetailLine;
    public static final String pspace = "               ";//15-spaces

    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {

        df.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String strText = null;
        final String LF = "\n";// text string to output
        int lineStart;           // start index of line in textarea
        int lineEnd;             // end index of line in textarea
        int lineNumber;
        int lineCount;
        final String SPACE = "          ";//10 spaces
        final String SPACES = "         ";//9
        final String uline = "________________________________________";
        final String dline = "----------------------------------------";
        String greetings = "THANKS FOR YOUR VISIT";
        receiptDetailLine = "asdasdasda";

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        Font font = new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.BOLD, 9);

        if (pageIndex < 0 || pageIndex >= 1) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(10, 40);

 //testing
        textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append(" " + SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append("" + SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

        textarea.append(uline + "\n");
        textarea.append("Order Ref:" + "   " + receiptDetailLine + "\n");
        textarea.append(dline + "\n");
        textarea.append(" Qty     Description" + SPACES + "  Price" + LF);
        textarea.append(dline + "\n");

        System.out.println(2);

        String printedLine = "       Service Charge Complimentary";
        textarea.append(printedLine + LF);

        textarea.append(LF + SPACES + "   Your Reciept\n" + SPACE + greetings + LF);
        textarea.append(df.format(new Date()) + LF);
        textarea.setEditable(false);

        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

        g2d.setFont(font);
        lineNumber = 0;
        lineCount = textarea.getLineCount();
        strText = textarea.getText();
        /*MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(textarea);
         URL imageURL = null;
         try {

         imageURL = new URL(mainDirectory+"quindell.png");
         } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
         me.printStackTrace();
         }

         //--- Load the image and wait for it to load
         Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL);
         mt.addImage(image, 0);
         */

        while (lineCount != 0) {
            try {

                lineStart = textarea.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
                lineEnd = textarea.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber);
                strText = textarea.getText(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("Printing error:" + exception);                  // have to catch BadLocationException
            }

            g2d.drawString(strText, 1, (lineNumber + 1) * 18);
            //spacing    between lines
            lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
            lineCount--;
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i done this programming and its works for me fine.You might get some help from it.check it.

```
public class Receipt
{

PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
Paper paper = new Paper();

double paperWidth = 3;//3.25
double paperHeight = 500.69;//11.69
double leftMargin = 0.12;
double rightMargin = 0.10;
double topMargin = 0;
double bottomMargin = 0.01;

paper.setSize(paperWidth * 200, paperHeight * 200);
paper.setImageableArea(leftMargin * 200, topMargin * 200,
     (paperWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin) * 200,
     (paperHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin) * 200);

format.setPaper(paper);

PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
//testing 

PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
Printable printable = new ReceiptPrint();

format = printerJob.validatePage(format);
printerJob.setPrintable(printable, format);
try {
   printerJob.print(aset);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
class ReceiptPrint implements Printable {
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
String  receiptDetailLine ;
public static final String pspace="               ";//15-spaces

public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)  
throws PrinterException 
{

df.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String strText =null; 
final String LF = "\n";// text string to output
int lineStart;           // start index of line in textarea
int lineEnd;             // end index of line in textarea
int lineNumber;   
int lineCount;
final String SPACE = "          ";//10 spaces
final String SPACES = "         ";//9
final String uline ="________________________________________";
final String dline ="----------------------------------------";
String greetings ="THANKS FOR YOUR VISIT";
receiptDetailLine= Integer.toString(SystemConfig.currentLocationCode) + "-"
+ Integer.toString(SystemConfig.tillNumber) + "-" + 
Integer.toString(EPOSFrame.mainFrame.currentUser.data.userID) + "-" + 
Receipt.order.name;

   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
Font font = new Font("MONOSPACED",Font.BOLD, 9);

if (pageIndex < 0 || pageIndex >= 1) {
      return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
  }
 JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(10,40);

 //testing
 if(SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine1!="")
 {
 textarea.append(SPACES+SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine1 +"\n");
 }
 if(SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine2!="")
 {
 textarea.append(" "+SPACES+SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine2 +"\n");
 }
 if(SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine3!="")
 {
 textarea.append(SPACES+SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine3 +"\n");
 }
 if(SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine5!="")
 {
 textarea.append(""+SPACES+SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine5 +"\n");
 }
 if(SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine4!="")
 {
 textarea.append(SPACES+SystemConfig.receiptAddressLine4 +"\n");
 }
 textarea.append(uline+"\n");
 textarea.append("Order Ref:" +"   "+receiptDetailLine+"\n");
 textarea.append(dline+"\n");
 textarea.append(" Qty     Description"+SPACES+"  Price"+LF);
 textarea.append(dline+"\n");

System.out.println(2);
TransactionItemPayment payment = null;
Enumeration transEnumeration = Receipt.order.m_transactions.elements();
int qty= 0;
String desc= "";
while (transEnumeration.hasMoreElements())
{

  TransactionItem ti = (TransactionItem) transEnumeration.nextElement();
  StringBuffer  price = new StringBuffer(String.valueOf(ti.getValue()));
  String  printLine = ti.getReceiptLine();

  if (printLine!=null)
  {
    qty=ti.getQuantity();
    desc = ti.getTopDisplayLine();


    if (price.length()>=2)
    {
      price.insert(price.length() - 2, '.');
    }


    textarea.append( printLine+LF );
    qty=0;
    desc="";

  }
  else if (ti instanceof TransactionItemPayment)
  {
    payment = (TransactionItemPayment) ti;
  }
  }
 long  serviceCharge = Receipt.order.calcServiceCharge();
 if (serviceCharge>0)
 {
  double  charge = (double) serviceCharge / 100;
  String  valueString = 
  SystemConfig.decimalFormat.format(charge).replace((char)163,' ');
  String printedLine = "       Service Charge    " +SPACE+ valueString;
  textarea.append( printedLine + LF);
}
else if (SystemConfig.serviceCharge)
{
  String printedLine = "       Service Charge Complimentary";
  textarea.append( printedLine + LF);
}
long  autoDiscount = Receipt.order.calcAutoDiscount();
if (autoDiscount>0)
{
  double  discount = (double) autoDiscount / 100;
  String  valueString =  
  SystemConfig.decimalFormat.format(discount).replace((char)163,' ');
  String printedLine = "       Discount:"+pspace+valueString;
  textarea.append( printedLine + LF);
}

long total = (long)Receipt.order.getOrderTotal() +  

  Receipt.order.calcServiceCharge() - Receipt.order.calcAutoDiscount();
  String formattedTotal = SystemConfig.decimalFormat.format((double)total /
  100D);

textarea.append(LF+"       SubTotal:"+pspace+formattedTotal+LF);
textarea.append("            Gratuity:______________________"+LF);//12 space
textarea.append("              Total:_______________________"+LF);
textarea.append("            Signature:_____________________"+LF);

textarea.append(LF+SPACES+"   Your Reciept\n"+ SPACE+greetings+LF);
textarea.append(df.format(new Date()) + LF);
textarea.setEditable(false);

  g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());


  g2d.setFont(font);
  lineNumber = 0;
  lineCount = textarea.getLineCount();
   strText = textarea.getText();
   /*MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(textarea);
   URL imageURL = null;
   try {

     imageURL = new URL(mainDirectory+"quindell.png");
   } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
     me.printStackTrace();
   }

 //--- Load the image and wait for it to load
   Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL);
   mt.addImage(image, 0);
   */

  while (lineCount!=0){
  try {

        lineStart = textarea.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
        lineEnd = textarea.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber);
        strText = textarea.getText(lineStart, lineEnd-lineStart);
        } catch( Exception exception) 
        {
            System.out.println("Printing error:" + exception);                  // have to catch BadLocationException
        }

                   g2d.drawString(strText,1,(lineNumber + 1) *18);
                   //spacing    between lines
                    lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
                     lineCount--;
         }
         return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
     }
    }
```