# Print Receipt in Java with some Font Size

Tags: java, printing, fonts, textarea

I tried to print POS receipt with code that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336607/thermal-printer-java). It's works fine but I want to have some different font sizes in the receipt. After searching in the forum, I just found out that a JTextArea just only can have 1 font. So, How can it be done? I'm new in Java so I'm prefer a simple solution for this, Thanks.

```
public class NewClass {

public void a() {
    PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
    Paper paper = new Paper();

    double paperWidth = 3;//3.25
    double paperHeight = 3.69;//11.69
    double leftMargin = 0.12;
    double rightMargin = 0.10;
    double topMargin = 0;
    double bottomMargin = 0.01;

    paper.setSize(paperWidth * 200, paperHeight * 200);
    paper.setImageableArea(leftMargin * 200, topMargin * 200,
            (paperWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin) * 200,
            (paperHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin) * 200);

    format.setPaper(paper);

    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);


    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    Printable printable = new ReceiptPrint();

    format = printerJob.validatePage(format);
    boolean don = printerJob.printDialog();
    printerJob.setPrintable(printable, format);
    try {
        printerJob.print(aset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

class ReceiptPrint implements Printable {

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
String receiptDetailLine;
public static final String pspace = "               ";//15-spaces

public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
        throws PrinterException {

    df.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String strText = null;
    final String LF = "\n";// text string to output
    int lineStart;           // start index of line in textarea
    int lineEnd;             // end index of line in textarea
    int lineNumber;
    int lineCount;
    final String SPACE = "          ";//10 spaces
    final String SPACES = "         ";//9
    final String uline = "________________________________________";
    final String dline = "----------------------------------------";
    String greetings = "THANKS FOR YOUR VISIT";
    receiptDetailLine = "asdasdasda";

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    Font font = new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.BOLD, 9);

    if (pageIndex < 0 || pageIndex >= 1) {
        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(10, 40);


    textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

    textarea.append(" " + SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

    textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

    textarea.append("" + SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

    textarea.append(SPACES + "sadasdsad" + "\n");

    textarea.append(uline + "\n");
    textarea.append("Order Ref:" + "   " + receiptDetailLine + "\n");
    textarea.append(dline + "\n");
    textarea.append(" Qty     Description" + SPACES + "  Price" + LF);
    textarea.append(dline + "\n");

    System.out.println(2);

    String printedLine = "       Service Charge Complimentary";
    textarea.append(printedLine + LF);

    textarea.append(LF + SPACES + "   Your Reciept\n" + SPACE + greetings + LF);
    textarea.append(df.format(new Date()) + LF);
    textarea.setEditable(false);

    g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

    g2d.setFont(font);
    lineNumber = 0;
    lineCount = textarea.getLineCount();
    strText = textarea.getText();
    /*MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(textarea);
     URL imageURL = null;
     try {

     imageURL = new URL(mainDirectory+"quindell.png");
     } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
     me.printStackTrace();
     }

     //--- Load the image and wait for it to load
     Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL);
     mt.addImage(image, 0);
     */

    while (lineCount != 0) {
        try {

            lineStart = textarea.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
            lineEnd = textarea.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber);
            strText = textarea.getText(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Printing error:" + exception);                  // have to catch BadLocationException
        }

        g2d.drawString(strText, 1, (lineNumber + 1) * 18);
        //spacing    between lines
        lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
        lineCount--;
    }
    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
}
```

Comment: Well, the code seems quite strange. It seems as if the TextArea is only created to set the layout, but the font is sent directly to the `g2d` instance... Maybe use different TextArea Instances for each font size (assuming you don't need to change font inside a Line), this would be the easiest if this code block is working... However, the code seems quite error-prone, I would prefer to understand how the library works and look for a more robust solution... :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Hope this will help you..

First of All Text of JTextArea are printed from N to 0.

You can specify condition according to line number to change the Font as below.

```
    while (lineCount != 0) {
        try {
            lineStart = textarea.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
            lineEnd = textarea.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber);
            strText = textarea.getText(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart);
            System.out.println("To be Print is : " + strText + " :" + lineCount);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            loger.error(ex);
        }
        **if(lineNumber==3) {
            g2d.setFont(new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.ITALIC, 13));
        }**
        g2d.drawString(strText, 1, (lineNumber + 1) * 18);
        lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
        lineCount--;
    }
```

Where condition lineNumber==3 changes the font. You can set old font in else part.